# Xcode 5, xib localization causes black screen on phone

Tags: ios, xcode, localization

I have an iPhone app on Xcode 5.0. I localized a `UIViewController` .xib file (English and Italian).

When running the app on phone and simulator, then loading the ViewController, the device shows a black screen. No exception or warning in console. Before localization the app was running fine.

Do you have any idea? Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: refer to my answer below, and let me know if it resolves your issue.

Answer (score 2):

First I would try this:

1. Quit the simulator
2. Clean your project(Under Product, Clean, or shift-cmd-'k')
3. Build your project(Under Product, Build, or cmd-'b')
4. Re-run your application

If that does not work. You can try, with your simulator open, `- Go to iOS simulator tab -> click reset content and settings`.